# Integration of function help

Tags: statistics, integration

I'm having problems integrating this function $\displaystyle E(X)=\int^ \infty_0 x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$. I did the integration by parts and had $-xe^{-\lambda x}- \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. However the solution gives $-xe^{-\lambda x} - \dfrac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda x}$. I can't find any mistakes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should share the details of your solution so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating by parts using $u=x \Rightarrow du=dx$ and $dv= e^{-\lambda x} dx \Rightarrow v = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx & = \lambda \int x e^{-\lambda x} dx \\
& = \lambda \left [\frac{xe^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda} - \int \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{(-\lambda)} dx\right] \\
& = \lambda \left [\frac{-xe^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda} + \int \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda} dx\right] \\
& = \lambda \left [\frac{-xe^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda} + \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda(-\lambda)} dx\right] \\
& = \lambda \left [\frac{-xe^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda} - \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda^2} \right] \\
& = -xe^{-\lambda x} - \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}. \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx & = \left[-xe^{-\lambda x} - \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}\right]_0^\infty \\
& = \left[\left(0 - 0\right) - \left(0 - \frac{1}{\lambda}\right) \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{\lambda}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$\begin{align*}\int\lambda xe^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\lambda\int\underbrace{x}_u\,\underbrace{e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x}_{\mathrm{d}v}\\&=\lambda\left(-\frac1\lambda xe^{-\lambda x}+\frac1\lambda\int e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\&=\lambda\left(-\frac1\lambda xe^{-\lambda x}-\frac1{\lambda^2}e^{-\lambda x}\right)\\&=-e^{-\lambda x}\left(x+\frac1\lambda\right)\end{align*}$$... and so$$\begin{align*}\int_0^\infty\lambda xe^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_0^c\lambda xe^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\lim_{c\to\infty}\left[-e^{-\lambda x}\left(x+\frac1\lambda\right)\right]_0^c\\&=\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(-e^{-\lambda c}\left(c+\frac1\lambda\right)+\frac1\lambda\right)\\&=\frac1\lambda\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle  \int x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$

$\displaystyle \lambda\int x e^{-\lambda x} dx$

Integrating by parts we have

$\displaystyle \lambda \left(x\int  e^{-\lambda x} dx-\int\dfrac{dx}{dx}\left(\int  e^{-\lambda x} dx\right) dx\right)$

$\displaystyle \lambda \left(\frac{xe^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda}-\int \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda} dx\right)$

$\displaystyle -xe^{-\lambda x}+\int e^{-\lambda x} dx$

$\displaystyle -xe^{-\lambda x}+\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{-\lambda}$

$\displaystyle -xe^{-\lambda x}-\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda}$

Comment: wow cant believe i missed that v should equal $-\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}$ where i had  is as $-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

Comment: [NP](http://image.naldzgraphics.net/2011/03/3-practice.jpg)